# Python: Access elements of a binary string as if there are no spaces between

Tags: python, list, binary-string

I have a list of couple like this `('01 0 00 0',key0), ('01 0 11 0',key1), ('01 0 11 1',key2)` and I would like to pick the elements with only the third and fourth bit equal to 1. So for example in this case I'll get `('01 0 11 0',key1) and ('01 0 11 1',key2)`.

How can I pick the couple with these elements ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in list_couples if i[0].split(" ")[2]=="11"]
```

If the spaces are not always the same:

```
l = [i for i in list_couples if i[0].replace(" ", "")[3:5]=="11"]
```

Comment: will only work if the spaces pattern is always the same as in examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use list comprenhension, like this:

```py
tuples = [('01 0 00 0',key0), ('01 0 11 0',key1), ('01 0 11 1',key2)]

res = [(s, k) for (s, k) in tuples if s.split(' ')[2] == '11']
```